# Expressing virtual force in terms of muscle contraction force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, vectors

Two bodies connected with a hinge joint with axis in J. They also connected with a muscle at points M and M`. I’m trying to express virtual force Fv in terms of muscle force Fm acting at the point M in $\Bbb R^3$:

[image: forces diagram]

Torque generated by virtual force Fv at the joint J can be calculated as

$\tau = JV \times Fv$

where JV is a distance vector and Fv is a virtual force vector.

Then we converting torque $\tau$ into tangential force Fp acting at the point of muscle attachment M (like was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26200213/finding-out-force-from-torque-and-distance))

$Fp = \frac{\tau \times JM}{|JM|^2}$

where JM is a vector distance and |JM| is a magnitude of this distance.

The question is: how to find vector force **Fm** acting along the muscle MM`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The torque supplied by $F_m$ results in the torque due to $F_v$, so these torques are equal :
$\vec {JV} \times \vec F_v = \vec {JM} \times \vec F_m$.

*Evaluation* :

(a) either $\vec A \times \vec B = (AB \sin\theta) \hat k$ where $A$, $B$ are magnitudes and $\theta$ is the angle between

(b) or $(A_x \hat i+A_y\hat j) \times (B_x\hat i+B_y\hat j) = (A_xB_y - A_yB_x)    \hat k$.

Comment: @philip_0008 : Yes, my mistake.  Thanks for pointing it out.  I shall edit.

Comment: sounds like a plan! Unfortunately I have problems solving this kinds of proportions involving cross  products, so I asked another related question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837287/how-to-solve-proportions-involving-vector-cross-products

Comment: @ILICH : I have edited to indicate how to work out the cross products.  (Sorry, since you used them in your question I assumed you are familiar with them.)

Comment: @sammygerbil thank you Sammy, I thought I know what cross products are on some basic level, I use them very actively in game development, but I still can't understand how to express Fm from that equation, even after explanations that you've added. Sorry, but its just not something obvious for me. Will greatly appreciate your help if you can go a bit further and explain derivation for Fm in terms of Fv, JV and JM.

Comment: @sammygerbil by the way, my vectors are in R3, sorry for not mentioning this from the very beginning.

Comment: @ILICH : Sorry, I don't want to do all the work here.  Decide which method you want to use.  Then either : (a) calculate magnitudes and angles between vectors; or (b) write each vector in terms of components.  The muscle and bones all lie in the same plane, so this is a 2D problem, not 3D.

Comment: @sammygerbil oh, don't be sorry, its all good. I'll figure it out somehow.

Comment: marking as accepted, for more detailed derivation please refer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1837287/how-to-solve-proportions-involving-vector-cross-products